# log4j2 to chainsaw not working - nothing shows up in the 'Zeroconf' tab of Chainsaw

Tags: java, log4j2, zeroconf, apache-chainsaw

I am trying to to use Chainsaw to view my application's logger events but there is nothing showing up under the 'Zeroconf' tab in chansaw.

I've followed [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251303/scott)'s guide in [log4j2 to chainsaw hello world not working… what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474939/log4j2-to-chainsaw-hello-world-not-working-what-am-i-doing-wrong/16486023#16486023) - but no luck.  I was going to comment on that question asking how teryet got it working in the end, but as my reputation is below 50, the site didn't allow me.

**Environment**
OS: OSX Mavericks
IDE: Netbeans 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
Java: 1.7.0_45; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.45-b08
log4j: 2.0rc1
Chainsaw: downloaded the latest DMG from http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy/

**Things I've made sure**
- included jmdns.jar in the classpath of my application
- Used PatternLayout in my config log4j.xml
- Ensure advertiser URL has three slashes

**My log4j.xml config file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration status="OFF" advertiser="multicastdns">
        <appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
              <PatternLayout pattern="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %logger{3}.%style{%method}{Blue}%style{(line%line)}{Red}%X %highlight{%-5level} - %msg%n%xEx"/>
            </Console>
            <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="../logs/POS.log" filePattern="../logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/POS-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.log">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %logger{3}.%style{%method}{Blue}%style{(line%line)}{Red}%X %highlight{%-5level} - %msg%n%xEx"/>
                <Policies>
                    <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile> 
            <File name="testFile" fileName="../logs/POS2.log" bufferedIO="false" advertiseURI="file:///localhost/Users/arthurhsieh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AES/logs/POS2.log" advertise="true">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n"/>
            </File>
        </appenders>
        <loggers>
            <root level="all"> <!-- <root level="trace"> -->
                <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
                <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
                <appender-ref ref="testFile" />
            </root>
        </loggers>
    </configuration>
```

I can see logger events in the POS2.log file though.

Thanks in advance for any help/guidances.  Cheers.

Comment: Scott's guide mentions that the URI must be accessible network-wise, which for me (by opening in Chrome, for example), only works without the localhost part: file:///Users/arthurhsieh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AES/logs/POS2.log  Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue went away after I restarted my system, i.e., Chainsaw is working and i can view my logs by connecting through the Zeroconf tab.

My guess is this is an Apple OS issue rather than Chainsaw itself.